# AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'whoosh_search'

Tags: python, flask, full-text-search, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-whooshee

I am using `Flask` (`python`), creating `whooshe` search, I have followed all steps from this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-WhooshAlchemy),  also tried from other links too, but every time at end I came to this error:

```
results = BlogPost.query.whoosh_search('cool')
AttributeError:'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'whoosh_search'
```

Here is my model code:

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blogpost'
    __searchable__ = ['title', 'content']
    __analyzer__ = StemmingAnalyzer()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode) # Indexed fields are either String,
    content = db.Column(db.Text) # Unicode, or Text
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

I am having error on this:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    results = BlogPost.query.whoosh_search('cool')
return results
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen this error.Then I found the error is in models.py.You should add the `whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, BlogPost)` at the end of the model code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar issue if anyone falls down thsi rabbit hole.

In my case, i found that in my `models.py` i was importing from sqlalchemy and using the declarative_base as a base for each model.
ie:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, DateTime, Text, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Book(Base):
```

while in my `routes.py` I was importing `flask-sqlalchemy` where you use db.Model as the base:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)

class Book(db.Model):
```

There have been some similar answers on some other posts as well but it looks like when using flask-whooshalchemy or its similar variants (whooshalchemy3, whooshalchemyplus) using db.Model as the base is the correct way to init the model to have the appropriate attributes.

hopefully that helps someone down the road.